# Logstash not reading logs unless world-readable

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, logstash

I recently set up Logstash with Kibana and Elasticsearch, but am having a problem whereby it's not reading logs unless the directory permissions are world read/execute (and the files at least world read).

I've installed version 1.4.2 from the RPM, which runs as the logstash user.  I've made sure the logstash user is a member of the groups relating to logs it needs to read, e.g. "apache".

```
[root@rhel-00081 conf]# id logstash
uid=497(logstash) gid=497(logstash) groups=48(apache),10081(nexus),27666(spark),497(logstash)
```

The default permission on /var/log/http is `drwxr-x--- root apache`, yet Logstash will not process the logs until I change this to `drwxr-xr-x`

Any idea why this is?

Comment: Have you restarted logstash after it was given that group membership? Please show the output from `pgrep logstash`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have discovered the problem.  The init script supplied in the RPM starts logstash as follows:

```
nice -n ${LS_NICE} chroot --userspec $LS_USER:$LS_GROUP / sh -c "
cd $LS_HOME
ulimit -n ${LS_OPEN_FILES}
exec \"$program\" $args
" > "${LS_LOG_DIR}/$name.stdout" 2> "${LS_LOG_DIR}/$name.err" &
```

But when running under the chroot command, all secondary group membership is removed unless you supply the --groups option. You can see this if you run:

```
[root@rhel-00081 ~]# chroot --userspec logstash:logstash / bash -c "id"
uid=497(logstash) gid=497(logstash) groups=497(logstash),0(root)
```

Therefore the apache logs are unreadable...

```
[root@rhel00081 httpd]# chroot --userspec logstash:logstash / bash -c "cat /var/log/httpd/access_log"
cat: /var/log/httpd/access_log: Permission denied
```

The chroot line in the init script needs to be preceded with something like:

```
SUPP_GROUPS=$(groups $LS_USER | cut -d " " -f 4- | tr " " ",")
SUPP_GROUP_STR=""
if [ ! -z ${SUPP_GROUPS} ]
then
  SUPP_GROUP_STR="--groups=${SUPP_GROUPS}"
fi
```

and then modify the beginning of the chroot line:

```
nice -n ${LS_NICE} chroot ${SUPP_GROUP_STR} --userspec=$LS_USER:$LS_GROUP / sh -c "
... etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in the logstash 1.4.2 init script.
https://github.com/elastic/logstash/pull/1398